# spring-boot-gradle-plugin breaks dependency cache strategy

Tags: gradle, spring-boot, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

My project depends a changing module(foo, a maven SNAPSHOT dependency) for debug, foo is always changing.
After i add `apply plugin 'spring-boot'`, foo is cached for a long long time.
**what should i do to let changing module works fine with spring-boot plugin?**

```
//my build.gradle file.
apply plugin 'spring-boot' // bad boy
dependencies {
    compile('foo:foo:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT') { changing = true }
}
project.configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.cacheChangingModulesFor 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS
    resolutionStrategy.cacheDynamicVersionsFor 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dependencyManagement {
    resolutionStrategy {
        cacheChangingModulesFor 0, 'seconds'
    }
}
```

[more details from github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7411)